# Selecting specific columns with generative selects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm learning SQL alchemy and going through the [Expression Language Tutorial](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/tutorial.html). I really like the generative selects because I can use table reflection and then easily query the table with Table class methods. This is what I'm doing now to do what I want.

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, create_engine, MetaData
engine = create_engine('mysql://...')
meta.bind = engine
table = Table('footable', meta, autoload=True)

result = table.select().where(...).execute()
```

I've written many selects before and I always select the specific columns that I need rather than selecting all. Is there a way to specify which columns to return in my SQL alchemy select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more on the [select()](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select) in the documentation, especially in respect to first two parameters.
But the following should be the right direction for you to work:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, and_, or_, not_
# ...
query = select(# what to select (tables or columns)
               [table.c.column1, table.c.column2],
               # filters (use any expression using and_, or_, not_...
               and_(table.c.column1.like("j%")),
               )
result = query.execute()
```

Comment: I saw that you could use the select object just as you your example does here. I was hoping I could select columns with the select method that's provided by the Table class. Otherwise, yes I know you can select columns like your example.

Comment: Well, `Table.select(...)` is just calling the `select(...)` with `self` as a parameter: `return select([self], whereclause, **params)`. This means you cannot select specific columns at this point.